# jQuery how to use numeric variables in your selectors

Tags: jquery

This is probably really trivial but I can't seem to find it, or maybe I'm not searching for the right words.

All I want is to make one function for all my selectors, they have corresponding numbers on them. Currently I have working functions but I feel there's a better way to code it.

Notice I have to make functions for every button-1 & cursusnummer1 / button-2 & cursusnummer2

So How Can I turn this into 1 instead of 3

HTML

```
<ul id="cursusnummer1">
    <li>20-4-2020 – Amsterdam – 13:00</li>
    <li>24-4-2020 – Utrecht – 15:00</li>
    <li>11-5-2020 – Groningen – 13:00</li>
    <li>19-5-2020 – Haarlem – 15:00</li>
    <li>22-6-2020 – Overveen – 11:00</li>
</ul>

<a class="button-1" target="_self" data-cursus="Cursus 1 - Title" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal.cursus"><span>Button Text</span></a>
```

jQuery

```
   jQuery('.button-1').click(function () {
        jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            const dates = jQuery('#cursusnummer1 li').map((i, li) => jQuery(li).text()).get();           
            //stuff    
        });
    });
    jQuery('.button-2').click(function () {
        jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            const dates = jQuery('#cursusnummer2 li').map((i, li) => jQuery(li).text()).get();
            //stuff
        });
    });
    jQuery('.button-3').click(function () {
        jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            const dates = jQuery('#cursusnummer3 li').map((i, li) => jQuery(li).text()).get();
            //stuff
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you add a new `shown.bs.modal` event handler on every click of a button?

Comment: What do you hope to select with this selector anyway? Is there a DOM element `<shown>`?

Comment: @Andreas because there's different courses on the page that have different forms, i am populating the forms with a  list of dates

Comment: This doesn't explain why you add a new handler **for the same event on always the same element** but with different behavior. First click -> one handler, second click -> two handlers for the same event, third click -> three handlers for the same event, ...

Comment: I guess that's why i feel the way im doing it now is wrong, it works but it feels (and probably is, judging from your comment) wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` symbol for the parameter initial substring, else you can use `$` symbol for the parameter end substring or else again you can use `*` symbol for the parameter that contains that substring.

Here's the example:

```
jQuery('[class^=button-]').click(function () {
    jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        const dates = jQuery('[id^=cursusnummer] li').map((i, li) => jQuery(li).text()).get();           
        //stuff    
    });
```

Hope this answer works for you

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close a `]`, try it now; anyway I need to know if `#cursusmodal` is the only id with that name in your HTML file

Comment: I added the ] myself, didnt do anything.
#cursusmodal is unique . 
the button class has numbers corresponding to the id after #cursusnummer

Comment: Let me know if copying this code (yeah, I saw that there were one ` more than needed...) returns some kind of error in console

Comment: It doesn't give any error. It just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see, you want only one function for all your selector. Since each selector has a number on then you can use the number. Use  the attr function to read the class and split it. you will get an array with index 1 being the number of your selector, then just use the number for your next selector.

```
      jQuery('[class^=button-]').click(function () {
         let ids=$(this).attr("class").split("-"); 
         jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
         const dates = jQuery('#cursusnummer'+ids[1]+' li').map((i, li) => 
            jQuery(li).text()).get();           
               //stuff   
             });
          });
```

Comment: Thats's close, I need it for the first one too (the button-1) because there's gonna be multiple buttons on the page linking to different populated forms

Comment: Try replacing `jQuery('.button-1')` with   `jQuery('[class^=button-]')` , that will make the click handle to all buttons with class button

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do multi selectors using a class, add an extra class to all your buttons called button, for example do:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function () {
        jQuery('#cursusmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            const dates = jQuery(this).find("li").map((i, li) => jQuery(li).text()).get();           
            //stuff    
        });
    });
```

Comment: no because the buttons and the #cursusnummer elements have information in them iuse to populate a form in the modal im calling

Comment: Where is the info? Can you explain and might help me gove you a better solution, i use something similar to what i have given you :)

Comment: I updated my post with the HTML, is that what you mean?

Comment: https://nieuwesite.thetreeclimbingcompany.com/opleiding-cursussen/

Here you can see the actual working example with my own ugly code

Comment: The jquery(this) find li, will get the info from the link that was clicked, if the button class was clicked on one element it will still get the info from that element.

Comment: So if i click the button class that is on button 1, i will get info from button1, same from button 2 etc. This is where JQuery is really good

Comment: It needs to get info from a button AND a div where the li is, otherwise it gives me all the info between <li> <li> on the whole page